# Creating Trigger (get value of the field from other object)

Tags: triggercontext, trigger

I am newbie or should I say starting to learn creating trigger. I hope you may help me in creating a trigger for the scenario below:

**Object Relationship:**
Account – Master
Territory Field (TSF_Vod__c)  Master-Detail(Account)
Call (Call2_vod__c)  Lookup(Account)

**Fields:**
Fieldname: Last Call Date (this field is in the Territory Field object)
API: Last_Activity_Date_vod__c

The fields below are in the Call object
Fieldname: Call Date/Time 
API: Call_Datetime_vod__c

Fieldname: Status
API: Status_vod__c

**Logic:**
If Call is created by the Account owner, then the Status is submitted or not null, the Last Call Date field should get the value of the Call Date/Time field of the newly created call record in the Account.

*Edit*

I tried to create the trigger below:

```
trigger Eisai_UpdateLastCallDateFromTSF on Call2_vod__c (before insert,before update) 
{ 
Map<Id, TSF_Vod__c> tsfList = new Map<Id,TSF_Vod__c>();
for(Call2_vod__c cv:Trigger.New) 
{ 
   if(cv.Status_vod__c = 'Submitted_vod' && cv.Status_vod__c != NULL) 
   { 
      tstList.Last_Activity_Date_vod__c = cv.Trigger.new.get(cv.ID).Call_Datetime; 
   } 
} 
}
```

Comment: You don't need a trigger, I think you are able to use a combination of field update (workflow rule) and a roll up summary field.

Comment: @developer__c: The Call object and Territory Field does have a relationship at all. However, can you please show me a direction on how to accomplish it with your suggestion? Thanks